# Employers Page on Jobs

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

The stats on the [employers](http://jobs.stackoverflow.com/default.asp?pg=pgEmployers) page at jobs.stackoverflow.com are woefully out of date.  We're short about a million unique visitors per month, ~300K questions and ~100 spots on either [Alexa](http://www.alexa.com/search?q=stackoverflow.com&r=home_home&p=bigtop) ranking.

Also I don't really get how that graph helps some hiring manager decide to use careers or jobs, it's just confusing and ugly.

Comment: We'll get someone to fix this right away!